# use ffmpeg to change framerate without losing quality and mantaining the same duration

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

first, i'm new to ffmpeg.
i've some videos in HD resolution and 50fps. I would like to halve the framerate keeping the same resolution and the same duration of the videos.
I've tried to remux them with ffmpeg, but it simply double the lentgh of the video to have 25 fps instead of 50 !

```
    ffmpeg -i source.mov -c copy mux.h264
    ffmpeg -r 25 mux.h264 -c copy remux.mov
```

how can i do it ? is the -c copy tag the problem ?
thanks !

Comment: `ffmpeg -i source.mov -c:a copy -r 25 remux.mov`

Comment: this script re encode the stream and lowers the bitrate. i would like to halve the framerate only

Comment: Then add a `-b:v X` where X is the source file's video bitrate.

Comment: i've tried -crf to have the same bitrate of the source, and it works. but the destination file have the same size of the source, even if it has half the frames ! the gspot video analyzer tells that the "qf", the factor of the frame quality, is doubled, but they have the same resolution and the same bitrare. can you tell me why ?

Comment: ok, maybe i've understood. the kbps of gspot is kbit for seconds; if the framerate is halved, the kbit for second must be halved too ! i was comparing the kbps to have the same value, actually doubling the frame quality !

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Gyan `ffmpeg -i source.mov -c:a copy -r 25 remux.mov` was (and is still) the solution !